# open app made with filemaker ios sdk (FIAS) from external url show error popup

Tags: ios, filemaker

i've made an app with Filemaker ios SDK (18) and it works flawless.

I need to open this app from another one or from safari, and i'm using the custom url schema.

(i follow this tutorial to create the appdelegate)

https://github.com/starsite/SwiftFM/blob/master/FIAS-Swift-AppDelegate-walkthrough.md

The app opens, but i've got this error popup (when i open app form external url).

[error popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpqDg.png)

EDIT:

if i build a simply swift app, it works all well, it's probably a bug in FM sdk 18 (or something undocumented)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like issue with URL. You have to make it in this view:

"fmp" should be changed on your own URL prefix.

```
fmp: //<user>:<pass>@<hostName>/<fileName> // user:pass

fmp: //<hostName>/<fileName>?script=<scriptName>&param=<parameter> // parameter

fmp: //<hostName>/<fileName>?script=<scriptName>&variable=<variable> // variable

fmp: //~/<fileName> // an unopened file, from ~/Documents

fmp: //$/<fileName> // currently open file
```

Source: 
https://community.claris.com/en/s/article/url-schemes-for-filemaker-go--app-sdk--and-swift

Comment: this url are to open fmp file on desktop client.
I need to use custom url schema of ios, i need to call my fmapp (not fmgo but wrapped with fm sdk) from another native app.
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app

Comment: This URL works the same for FileMaker iOS App SDK based apps too. If your fmp12 database is not hosted (local in Xcode project), then use the last URL from example above: fmp: //$/<fileName>

Comment: it works only if you have fmGO installed, not with FIAS app (sdk)

Comment: It works the same with FIAS apps too. Just replace fmp prefix with your own.